# Confidence intervals in SunSpider JavaScript Benchmark

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

How are the confidence intervals calculated in [SunSpider JavaScript Benchmarks](http://www2.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this works as following:

Every test has several runs.

```
1. take 95% close to average test runs times.
2. calculate percentage difference between those takes.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are computing it wrong since I don't see any standard deviation in your 'formula'. I read somewhere that they assume that runtimes have a Gamma distributions. For Gaussian distribution I remember that 95% confidence interval is `avg +/- 2*stdev/sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but [from the SunSpider source](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider-0.9.1/sunspider-compare-results.js):

```
var error = "+/- " + ((tDist(count) * stdErr / mean) * 100).toFixed(1) + "% ";
```

Where

```
var sqrtCount = Math.sqrt(count);
var stdErr = stdDev / sqrtCount;
```

Obviously, parts of the `var error =` statement human-readably format it for the results table.

(PS I used this an exercise to learn JavaScript; I hope I'm not completely off-base!)